# UIScrollView not working with [scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES]

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, iphone, ios-4.2

In my .h file, I have an IBOutlet declared like this:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

I wired my UIScrollView to File's Owner.

In my .m file I have the following in viewDidLoad:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

But when I try to scroll, nothing happens.

You don't need to set the UIScrollViewDelegate because I've had apps that scroll without using it.

Comment: Have a look at the PhotoScroller app you can download from the SDK site. It gives a all the details needed for setting up a UIScrollView

Comment: Is content size greater than view size?

Comment: The content size is 320 by 700. The view size is the default 320x480.

Answer (score 1):

If you a are using iOS 6, using **Autolayout** in your *.xib* files can be the reason that your `UIScrollView` doesn't behave the way you expect it to (even though your setting a large `contentSize`).

You can disable Autolayout by selecting the respective *.xib* file in the Project Navigator and unchecking "Autolayout" in the File inspector (in the right column).

You can also adjust your Autolayout settings (there's various threads on this).

Comment: This was my issue. Spent an hour looking for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have taken scroll view in xib file then you do not need to below line:

```
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Also you should check your connection with file's owner.